# How do I group, sort, and ffill dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to select rows from a pandas dataframe where column D = 1, I then want to group the selected rows by column A, and then use the [ffill function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to copy values from column C into the selected rows for the group - note that C's value varies by group.

Example - starting with this:

```
A       B        C         D
101     alpha    NaN       1
101     beta     NaN       1
103     alpha    NaN       1
102     alpha    NaN       0
102     beta     NaN       0
103     beta     NaN       0
101     delta    happy     1
102     delta    NaN       0
103     delta    sad       1
```

would like to end up with this:

```
A       B        C         D
101     alpha    happy     1
101     beta     happy     1
101     delta    happy     1
102     alpha    NaN       0
102     beta     NaN       0
102     delta    NaN       0
103     alpha    sad       1
103     beta     sad       1
103     delta    sad       1
```

I've been experimenting with groupby, sort_values, and ffill - but can't seem to get the order of operations right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be retrieved by sorting and grouping them together.

```
df = df.sort_values(['A','B'], ascending=[True,True])
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].fillna(method='bfill')
df

A   B   C   D
0   101 alpha   happy   1
1   101 beta    happy   1
6   101 delta   happy   1
3   102 alpha   NaN 0
4   102 beta    NaN 0
7   102 delta   NaN 0
2   103 alpha   sad 1
5   103 beta    sad 0
8   103 delta   sad 1
```